# Script Editor keeps opening up by itself

Tags: macos

I don't know why, but Script Editor opens up repeatedly. If I close it it will open back up again. There's nothing there, it's just a blank "script".

How do I figure out the launcher of an application? I took a screenshot of the active programs in my dock as well, maybe one of them is doing this?

[image]

Comment: If you fire up a terminal, use the process command and grep it through the name of the script editing software, it *should* tell you which application or process has called it into being.